# Is 12(mod 13) the same as -1(mod 13)?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm in the process of studying for an exam and this just popped into my head. Sorry if it's a dumb question

Comment: I am not sure you understand the "concept" of "$a\equiv b \pmod n$" or what this means: "$a\bmod n$". To answer your question, yes because $12\equiv-1\pmod{13}.$

Comment: $a\equiv a\pm n\pmod{n}$

Comment: Yes, because -1 + 1 = 0 = 0 mod 13; 12 + 1 = 13 = 0 mod 13

Comment: Boom... Here is an upvote too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are the same. Note that $(-1)+13=12$, so their difference is exactly the thing that is ignored by mod $13$!

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. It seems so clear now, I'm not sure why that confused me before

Answer (score 0):

Indeed they are the same, although I'd write them either without brackets or with brackets around the whole expression.

I really wanted to add that that using the $(-1 \bmod 13)$ representation can be very useful, especially when try to find the result of a multiplication. For a simple example, $12\times 7 \bmod 13$ is easily converted to $12\times 7 \equiv -1\times 7  \equiv -7 \equiv 4 \bmod 13$